# SUM the results of a CASE Statement

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am using the following code to count the records by Type in a table:

```
select null link, CASE when SUBSTR(PRJA_TYPE,1,3) ='CHO' then 'CHO'
  else PRJA_TYPE
END as label, 
COUNT(PRJA_TYPE) Contract_Type
from  "SPM"."PROJECT_AGREEMENTS"
where PRJA_ACTIVE = 1 and PRJA_TYPE IS NOT NULL
 group by PRJA_TYPE
order by PRJA_TYPE
```

It is giving me the following result:

```
LINK    LABEL   CONTRACT_TYPE

-       Ballpark   14 
-       CHO        7 
-       CHO        7 
-       CHO        6 
-       CHO        30 
-       CHO        11 
-       CHO        9 
-       CHO        1 
-       CHO        2 
-       LOA        9
```

This part is working as expected. I then need to SUM up the items in the Label Column that are marked CHO. So my final result would look like this:

```
LINK    LABEL   CONTRACT_TYPE

-       Ballpark   14 
-       CHO        73 
-       LOA        9
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: When you group by PRAJA_TYPE, the values containing starting with CHO are still grouped by PRAJA_TYPE not by just `CHO`.  Add PRAJA_Type to your select and you'll see why you have multiple CHO values.  Sufficient answers have been provided to explain how to resolve this issue.  Note you can't use the alias, as the order of execution fro the SQL has the group by occurring BEFORE the SELECT, thus the alias isn't known yet.

Comment: Thank you! That makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 1):

You need to aggregate by the expression:

```
select null as link,
       (case when SUBSTR(PRJA_TYPE, 1, 3) = 'CHO' then 'CHO'
             else PRJA_TYPE
        end) as label, 
       COUNT(*) Contract_Type
from  "SPM"."PROJECT_AGREEMENTS"
where PRJA_ACTIVE = 1 and PRJA_TYPE IS NOT NULL
group by (case when SUBSTR(PRJA_TYPE, 1, 3) = 'CHO' then 'CHO'
               else PRJA_TYPE
          end)
order by label;
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

cte would do i guess

```
with cte as
(select null link, CASE when SUBSTR(PRJA_TYPE,1,3) ='CHO' then 'CHO'
  else PRJA_TYPE
END as label, 
COUNT(PRJA_TYPE) Contract_Type
from  "SPM"."PROJECT_AGREEMENTS"
where PRJA_ACTIVE = 1 and PRJA_TYPE IS NOT NULL
 group by PRJA_TYPE
order by PRJA_TYPE
)

select link, label, sum(contract_type) contract_type from cte group by link,label
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use your case statement in your group-clause:

```
select 
  null link, 
  CASE when SUBSTR(PRJA_TYPE,1,3) ='CHO' then 'CHO' else PRJA_TYPE END as label, 
COUNT(PRJA_TYPE) Contract_Type
from  "SPM"."PROJECT_AGREEMENTS"
where PRJA_ACTIVE = 1 and PRJA_TYPE IS NOT NULL
group by CASE when SUBSTR(PRJA_TYPE,1,3) ='CHO' then 'CHO' else PRJA_TYPE END
order by PRJA_TYPE
```

As an alternative (e.g. if you can't modify your query) you can use a second query to sum your numbers up:

```
select link, label, sum(CONTRACT_TYPE)
from (
--your first query
) x
group by link, label
```